# How could I merge columns that share the same index value in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am trying to get all the people that work at a specific movie as numerical values instead of categorical but when I use a form of one hot encoder on this dataset:

```
titleId,nconst,category,characters
tt0035423,nm0000212,actress,"[""Kate McKay""]"
tt0035423,nm0413168,actor,"[""Leopold""]"
tt0035423,nm0000630,actor,"[""Stuart Besser""]"
tt0035423,nm0005227,actor,"[""Charlie McKay""]"
tt0035423,nm0003506,director,\N
```

I get this:

```
           x0_nm0000212  x0_nm0000630  x0_nm0003506  x0_nm0005227  x0_nm0413168
titleId                                                                        
tt0035423           1.0           0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0
tt0035423           0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0           1.0
tt0035423           0.0           1.0           0.0           0.0           0.0
tt0035423           0.0           0.0           0.0           1.0           0.0
tt0035423           0.0           0.0           1.0           0.0           0.0
```

How could I make it to combine the rows in the titleId column and only take the 1.0s like so:

```
           x0_nm0000212  x0_nm0000630  x0_nm0003506  x0_nm0005227  x0_nm0413168
titleId                                                                        
tt0035423           1.0           1.0           1.0           1.0           1.0
```

I thought about finding a way to add the column values on the same titleId but I could not find a way.

This is the code:

```
count = principals_data.head().nconst.value_counts()
principals_data = principals_data[
principals_data.nconst.isin(count.index)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like currently titleId is the index on which you want to apply groupby.

One option is to reset 'titleId' to column and get the max of each column.

```
df.reset_index().groupby('titleId').max()
```

**Output**

```
        x0_nm0000212    x0_nm0000630    x0_nm0003506    x0_nm0005227    x0_nm0413168
titleId                 
tt0035423     1.0        1.0            1.0          1.0     1.0
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I am every day impressed by how many things pandas can do and the programming community

Comment: Great, In that case you can accept the answer by clicking tick so that it is useful for people in future.

Answer (score 1):

[crosstab](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab) can be used to generate this directly from the source df.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'titleId': {0: 'tt0035423', 1: 'tt0035423',
                               2: 'tt0035423', 3: 'tt0035423',
                               4: 'tt0035423'},
                   'nconst': {0: 'nm0000212', 1: 'nm0413168',
                              2: 'nm0000630', 3: 'nm0005227',
                              4: 'nm0003506'},
                   'category': {0: 'actress', 1: 'actor',
                                2: 'actor', 3: 'actor',
                                4: 'director'},
                   'characters': {0: '["Kate McKay"]', 1: '["Leopold"]',
                                  2: '["Stuart Besser"]', 3: '["Charlie McKay"]',
                                  4: '\\N'}})

new_df = (
    pd.crosstab(df['titleId'], df['nconst'])
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
        .add_prefix('x0_')  # Add x0_ prefix to columns
        .astype(float)  # Convert to Float
)

# For Display
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
           x0_nm0000212  x0_nm0000630  x0_nm0003506  x0_nm0005227  x0_nm0413168
titleId                                                                        
tt0035423           1.0           1.0           1.0           1.0           1.0
```